# What sauce is Gordon Ramsey using for this dish?

Tags: sauce, beef

Gordon Ramsay has a trailer on YouTube for his MasterClass course. The link for the video is here: [Gordon Ramsay's MasterClass (YouTube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6gFISD70aoE).

I have attached the screenshot at 0:21

[image: Gordon Ramsay's MasterClass]

It looks like cream or something else - is that beef wellington too? What is that sauce as I wish to make this dish!

Thanks

Comment: that is not a beef Wellington, as it's not wrapped in puff pastry

Comment: I agree with @Luciano, it's just a fillet steak. I think the 'sauce' is actually _pommes puree_, essentially a very buttery, very smooth mashed potato.

Comment: Very, very, very buttery, typically 50-50 potato to butter mix believe it or not. Delicious but you can feel your arteries harden after eating it.

Comment: Thank you everyone - Please provide answers since cannot reward comments

Comment: And, as others have correctly answered, [here is the pomme purée version](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/1392/truffle-oil-pomme-pure) that Gordon Ramsay serves in his restaurants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sauce in question here is **pomme purée**. This was answered by the community but a special thanks to `@Luciano`, `@ElendilTheTall`, `@GdD` and `@Dorothy`.

Happy Cooking